# Property 'split' does not exist on type 'ArrayBuffer' in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, filereader

I was trying to read a CSV file using Filereader and want to convert the content into an array. I was able to get the CSV file properly, but whenever I want to convert the content of CSV file into an array I have this error.

---

Why do I have this error and how can i solve it?

```
    ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(31,10): error TS2314: Generic type 'Array<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
        src/app/app.component.ts(31,21): error TS2339: Property 'split' does not exist on type 'string | ArrayBuffer'.
          Property 'split' does not exist on type 'ArrayBuffer'.
```

---

Here is my app.component.html file:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="/docs/4.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top"
          alt="">
        Floor Plan
      </a>
    </nav>

    <div class="card m-5">
      <div class="row row-5">
        <div class="col-4">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="custom-file">
              <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile04" (change)="upload($event.target)">
              <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile04">Choose file</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Upload </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-8 border border-primary" >
          {{csvContent}}

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

---

here is my app.component.ts file:

```
    export class AppComponent {
      fileToUpload: File = null;
      title = 'floor-plan';
      csvContent: string[] = []



      upload(input: HTMLInputElement) {

        const files = input.files;
        var content = this.csvContent;

        if (files && files.length) {

          const fileToRead = files[0];

          const fileReader = new FileReader();
          fileReader.onload = (event) => {
            this.csvContent = (event.target as FileReader).result.split('\n').map((data) => {
              return data.split(',')
            })

          }

          fileReader.readAsText(fileToRead, "UTF-8");
        }

      }
     }
```

Comment: Well, the `ArrayBuffer` prototype simply does not have a `split()` method. What is it that you expect that to do anyway?

Comment: @Pointy - No, but it exists on `string`, which is what `result` will be when you use `readAsText`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah, OK then; so is this a TypeScript type system/declaration issue? Makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FileReader.result` can be either a string or an ArrayBuffer along its life. It starts being an ArrayBuffer, then, after the file is read, it gets converted to a string. The problem is, Typescript isn't happy about applying the `.split()` method to something that can be an ArrayBuffer at some point in time.

It *will* be a string at this point of the script execution; *you* know that, but Typescript doesn't.

In order to tell this to Typescript, cast it to a string like so :

```
this.csvContent = <string>((event.target as FileReader).result).split(...)
```

Then Typescript should stop complaining :)

Comment: thanks. exactly what I was looking for. upvoted @jeremy-thille

Answer (score 6):

The type of the `FileReader` `result` property is tricky for TypeScript, because it depends on what method you've called elsewhere in the code.

In your case, you're calling [`readAsText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText) so you know that `result` contains a string, not an `ArrayBuffer`, but TypeScript doesn't know that.

You'll need a type guard or type assertion. For instance, with a type guard:

```
fileReader.onload = (event) => {
  const result = fileReader.result;
  if (typeof result !== "string') {
    throw new Error("Unexpected result from FileReader");
  }
  this.csvContent = result.split('\n').map((data) => {
    return data.split(',')
  })
};
```

Or with a type assertion:

```
fileReader.onload = (event) => {
  this.csvContent = (fileReader.result as string).split('\n').map((data) => {
    return data.split(',')
  })
};
```

---

In both of the examples above, I've used `fileReader` rather than `event.target` since the `onload` handler closes over it.